# New to SQL needing help combining records with same ID from single table

Tags: sql, ms-access

Everyone, new to SQL Statements and need some help.

Table with 7 Fields:

```
ID     Address       Cycle     Service_Type    Status    Bill_Date    Consumption
6251   1016 Easy St    4            W            A       12/23/2015        6.0
6251   1016 Easy St    4            W            A        1/15/2016        4.0
6251   1016 Easy St    4            W            A        2/17/2016        4.0
.........(total of 14 records for each ID/Address consumption)
6251   1016 Easy St    4            W            A        1/18/2017        5.0
```

What I would like to end up with is a single record with all 14 Bill_Date and Consumption in it, something like this:

```
ID     Address       Cycle     Service_Type    Status    Bill_Date1   Consumption1 Bill_Date2   Comsumption2   Bill_Date3   Comsumption3 ... #14
6251   1016 Easy St    4            W            A       12/23/2015        6.0  1/15/2016   4.0    2/17/2017   4.0 and so on
```

I have a total of 6300 records with 450 unique ID's/Addresses each with 14 different bill dates and consumption numbers.

In the end, I want a table that has 450 records, each with the 14 different dates and consumption.

I sure do appreciate any help.

Just FYI: I am using MS Access 2016 to write the SQL statements in. I can't get SQL Server 2014 Management Studio to pull in any Excel, CSV or Access files. I am getting some kind of error that I will have to work through.

Comment: Do you know about the `DISTINCT` keyword ?

Comment: the tables in your question can be formatted using markdown so they're easier to read. As it is it's too difficult to see what's happening in them.

Comment: I suggest you solve your SQL 2014 issues first. SQL Server and Access have enough differences that a SQL 2014 will not compile or run in Access and vice versa. To Import files into SQL Server, follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in Access, I suggest you look at either the [Cross Tab Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) or the [Pivot View](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-views-in-an-Access-desktop-database-83e524df-dfbd-456d-9dd0-0a48c1aa6752?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#__toc273692282).

There are pretty comprehensive walkthroughs at the links above.